# How do I parse value from linkbutton inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Please observe this picture:

[image]

I want to be able to click that "15" ( or any of those other ones (they're all linkbuttons)) BatchID value and it fires an event, inside that event I want to be able to parse the value of the [linkbutton] value that was clicked.

So for instance if you clicked 22, inside the event it fires I want to be able to parse the value of the button that was clicked (22).

Here's my gridview code:

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="HSMGrid"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                DataKeyNames="Status"
                OnRowCommand="grdvwSearchDepositTransaction_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdSearch_RowDataBound" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                CssClass="grid" Width="650">
               <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderTemplate" />
               <FooterStyle CssClass="FooterTemplate" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BatchID">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnBatchId" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TransactionGroupsEntry.groupID") %>' OnClick="btnBatchId_Click" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TransactionGroupsEntry.groupID") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TransactionGroupsEntry.bankNumber" HeaderText="Bank" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TransactionGroupsEntry.branchNumber" HeaderText="Branch" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TransactionGroupsEntry.cashInTicketAmount" HeaderText="Cash-In Ticket Amount" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TransactionGroupsEntry.createdBy" HeaderText="Created By" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TransactionGroupsEntry.dateCreated" HeaderText="Date Created" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                        </Columns>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <span style="font-weight: bold;">No Transactions have been entered</span>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Here's the event it fires:

```
    protected void btnBatchId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: What means "the event its supposed to fire", does it already handle the click event or do you want it? I would use a template-field and a real `LinkButton`. Then you can use it's `Click`-event.

Comment: it does fire that event.

Comment: Are you looking for link button value after clicking the link ?

Comment: @NeerajDubey you got it brother

Comment: @Indianaadminstopstuck: just out of interest, how does it handle that event, `btnBatchId_Click` is nowhere subscribed?

Comment: @TimSchmelter not well. (bad joke) 

when you click like "15" (which is a linkbutton) it will fire the event I have annotated. The issue lays mostly with trying to parse the value of the linkbutton that was clicked.

Comment: use rowcommand in gridview.

Comment: @Indianaadminstopstuck: i still don't get it where you add the event-handler `btnBatchId_Click`. It's neither added declaratively(on the aspx) nor programmatically(in codebehind). Do you call it manually from `Row_Command`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have (5) grids in this program i'm writing, and I accidentally copied my previous grid please see my new edit to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to cast the `sender` to `LinkButton` and use it's `Text` property:

```
protected void btnBatchId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton link = (LinkButton) sender;
    string batchID = link.Text;
}
```

Comment: danke sehr! Thank you so much!